# generate route to other admin class

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I search over google for a long time, but I don't find any solution to my problem.

In fact I've got an entity, with two fields. One fields 'name' that is a string and a second field targetentity that is also a string containing a namespace to an entity. The namespace can be choice with a select and can be different. So I wan't in my sonata admin bundle when I'm on my list action make a link in the table to redirect to the route list of the entity select.

Someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the listview as described here: http://blog.webdevilopers.net/override-list-view-twig-template-in-sonataadminbundle/ or here: [Modifying list view in Sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747744/modifying-list-view-in-sonata)

In the list view you have the admin class available. What you can do is add a function in your admin that return the right url:

```
public function generateMyUrl($object){
    // add your logic here
    $url = $this->generateObjectUrl($name, $object, $parameters, $absolute);
    return $url;
}
```

In your inner_list_row template

```
<a href="{{ admin.generateMyUrl(object) }}" target="_blank">
    your link description
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a form with type choice read this link it will help you

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Comment: Hi, yes i've always got my choice make with list of all my entities in my project. And now i just want to generate link to admin class list of the entity select.

Comment: In my list of entities I don't have the admin class. Is there a way to retrieve in controller or other the admin class for a bundle for example? Thanks.