# Modifying list view in Sonata

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle for a Symfony project and I want to list entities not in table, but using vertical tabs. So, I want to have a tab, corresponding to each entity, so that pushing this tab opens fields selected by `configureListFields` at the right.

Is sonata capable of it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned on the [SonataAdmin documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/action_list.html), it is possible override the default templates Sonata uses to render the admin UI:

```
sonata_admin:
    templates:
        list: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list.html.twig
        inner_list_row: SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_inner_row.html.twig
        ...
```

The **list** template is reponsible for rendering the whole table.
The **inner_list_row** is responsible for rendering a single row in this table.

Actually, `list.html.twig` extends `base_list.html.twig`
and `list_inner_row.html.twig` extends `base_list_inner_row`,
so you should probably by overriding those four.